# Angular-ui/bootstrap: pagination not rendered (missing styles?)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm new to angular-ui and playing with it. I'm trying to use the pagination directive (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination), but it seems I'm missing some styles as I just see the unordered list rendered, rather than the expected pager UI. I included the following resources, in this order:

1) the latest (RC) **bootstrap CSS**: http://blog.netdna.com/opensource/bootstrapcdn/bootstrapcdn-now-serving-3-0-0-rc1/

2) **angular JS**: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js

3) **angular-ui/bootstrap**: I include from https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages the file ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js

My HTML sample body:

```
<body ng-app="Test">
<div ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl" class="well well-small">
    <pagination boundary-links="true" num-pages="noOfPages" current-page="currentPage" class="pagination-small" previous-text="'&lsaquo;'" next-text="'&rsaquo;'" first-text="'&laquo;'" last-text="'&raquo;'"></pagination>
</div>
<script>
var PaginationDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.noOfPages = 7;
  $scope.currentPage = 4;
  $scope.maxSize = 5;  
  $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
  };
};
var app = angular.module("Test", ["ui.bootstrap"]);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not your fault. Turns out angular UI is not 100% compatible with bootstrap 3 just yet. Most things work, but you can see the status in this issue: [Support bootstrap 3.0](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/331). I don't have the time to dive into this particular issue right now, but since *all the styles* are missing rather than some slightly broken thing, and all the functionality is fine, I bet it's an easy fix (renaming a class, etc). Meanwhile, you should either:

1. Switch to old boostrap
2. Write it yourself
3. Use the `<pager>` with new boostrap - I just tested it, and it works fine. So instead of `<pagination>` you want `<pager>`. A few fewer buttons but works for my purposes.

For instance:

```
<pager num-pages="numPages()" current-page="currentPage"></pager>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is encouraging for a noob :) Anyway, given that I'm starting a brand-new app using these techs I think it would be more future-savy to go for the latest version. Meantime, I'll do "manual" paging or try debugging the issue in the source (of course, we'll be happy if  anyone already has suggestions on this:). Just to test, I tried replacing the 3.0 RC CSS with the older version at href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css and it worked fine, but in my full app using 3.0 I fear this would not be so easy.

Comment: To whom may be interested, I applied a hack to be able to wait for a fix in the libs: I just pasted in my CSS the bootstrap CSS styles starting with .pagination, adding to each selector an ul, like ".pagination ul ...". As the generated HTML produces a div.pagination including an ul (which for some reason does not receive the pagination class), this is a quick (and dirty) fix.

Comment: awesome - I figured it was pretty simple.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to fix styling by following quick source code change:

in your ui-bootstrap file (mine was named ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.min.js) find following text:

```
<div class="pagination"><ul>
```

and then add `class="pagination"` to `<ul>` so it looks like this

```
<div class="pagination"><ul class="pagination">
```

Comment: It worked for me also. For non minimized variant of ui-bootstrap (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js), search pattern should be `<div class=\"pagination\">`

Answer (score 7):

I had an issue with pagination when I updated my angular-bootstrap version. It seems that they have changed the way we should use the directive.

before

```
<uib-pagination
    total-items="pagination.total_entries"
    ng-model="pagination.current_page"
    ng-change="pageChanged()">
</uib-pagination>
```

after

```
<ul uib-pagination
    total-items="pagination.total_entries"
    ng-model="pagination.current_page"
    ng-change="pageChanged()">
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me.

Comment: I had never used angular or asp.net before. Now following a tutorial and ran into this problem. It wasn't until after I realised that the angular github [pagination entry](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#pagination) was different tht I saw your solution, but I was still doubtful that converting to `<ul>` was the fix, so you get my upvote for clarifying.

Another problem though.. my styles are broken! It just displays a _working_ pagination list, but in plain text without any of the borders or positioning. Have you found a fix for this?

TIA!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and I changed the template to address the changes in Bootstrap 3:

```
angular.module("template/pagination/pagination.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/pagination/pagination.html",
    "<ul class=\"pagination\">\n" +
    "  <li ng-repeat=\"page in pages\" ng-class=\"{active: page.active, disabled: page.disabled}\"><a ng-click=\"selectPage(page.number)\">{{page.text}}</a></li>\n" +
    "</ul>\n" +
    "");
}]);
```

Just add the above wherever you created your modules.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same situation, but none of the above helped for me. The main problem was:

`ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js == (ui-bootstrap.min.js + html templates)` required by the js. If you only included `ui-bootstrap.min.js`, you will also need to provide your own html templates.

So dont use both of them, `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem using Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.3
and angular-ui-bootstrap 2.5.0

I fixed it by changing the ui-bootstrap-tpls.js pagination.html template to the following
`angular.module("uib/template/pagination/pagination.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("uib/template/pagination/pagination.html",
    "<li role=\"menuitem\" ng-if=\"::boundaryLinks\" ng-class=\"{disabled: noPrevious()||ngDisabled}\" class=\"page-item pagination-first\"><a href ng-click=\"selectPage(1, $event)\" ng-disabled=\"noPrevious()||ngDisabled\" class='page-link' uib-tabindex-toggle>{{::getText('first')}}</a></li>\n" +
    "<li role=\"menuitem\" ng-if=\"::directionLinks\" ng-class=\"{disabled: noPrevious()||ngDisabled}\" class=\"page-item pagination-prev\"><a href ng-click=\"selectPage(page - 1, $event)\" ng-disabled=\"noPrevious()||ngDisabled\" class='page-link' uib-tabindex-toggle>{{::getText('previous')}}</a></li>\n" +
    "<li role=\"menuitem\" ng-repeat=\"page in pages track by $index\" ng-class=\"{active: page.active,disabled: ngDisabled&&!page.active}\" class=\"page-item pagination-page\"><a href ng-click=\"selectPage(page.number, $event)\" class='page-link' ng-disabled=\"ngDisabled&&!page.active\" uib-tabindex-toggle>{{page.text}}</a></li>\n" +
    "<li role=\"menuitem\" ng-if=\"::directionLinks\" ng-class=\"{disabled: noNext()||ngDisabled}\" class=\"page-item pagination-next\"><a href ng-click=\"selectPage(page + 1, $event)\" class='page-link' ng-disabled=\"noNext()||ngDisabled\" uib-tabindex-toggle>{{::getText('next')}}</a></li>\n" +
    "<li role=\"menuitem\" ng-if=\"::boundaryLinks\" ng-class=\"{disabled: noNext()||ngDisabled}\" class=\"page-item pagination-last\"><a href ng-click=\"selectPage(totalPages, $event)\" class='page-link' ng-disabled=\"noNext()||ngDisabled\" uib-tabindex-toggle>{{::getText('last')}}</a></li>\n" +
    "");
}]);`

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by using this versions of `angular@~1.4.8` and `angular-bootstrap@~0.14.3`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  
      .controller('employeeController', function ($scope) {
     
   var employees = [{
    "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "City": "Berlin",
    "Country": "Germany"
  }, {
    "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
    "City": "Luleå",
    "Country": "Sweden"
  }, {
    "Name": "Blauer See Delikatessen",
    "City": "Mannheim",
    "Country": "Germany"
  }, {
    "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
    "City": "Strasbourg",
    "Country": "France"
  }, {
    "Name": "Bólido Comidas preparadas",
    "City": "Madrid",
    "Country": "Spain"
  }, {
    "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
    "City": "Strasbourg",
    "Country": "France"
  }, {
    "Name": "Bon app'",
    "City": "Marseille",
    "Country": "France"
  }, {
    "Name": "Bottom-Dollar Marketse",
    "City": "Tsawassen",
    "Country": "Canada"
  }, {
    "Name": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
    "City": "Buenos Aires",
    "Country": "Argentina"
  }, {
    "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
    "City": "México D.F.",
    "Country": "Mexico"
  }, {
    "Name": "Chop-suey Chinese",
    "City": "Bern",
    "Country": "Switzerland"
  }, {
    "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
    "City": "Strasbourg",
    "Country": "France"
  }, {
    "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
    "City": "Strasbourg",
    "Country": "France"
  }, {
    "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
    "City": "Strasbourg",
    "Country": "France"
  }, {
    "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
    "City": "Strasbourg",
    "Country": "France"
  }, {
    "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
    "City": "Strasbourg",
    "Country": "France"
  }, {
    "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
    "City": "Strasbourg",
    "Country": "France"
  }, {
    "Name": "Comércio Mineiro",
    "City": "São Paulo",
    "Country": "Brazil"
  }];
      $scope.employees=employees;
      
       $scope.pageSize = 10;
                $scope.currentPage = 1;
                $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.pageSize;
                $scope.maxSize = 5; //Number of pager buttons to show
                $scope.totalItems = $scope.employees.length;
                $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
                    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
                };

                $scope.pageChanged = function () {
                    console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
                };

                $scope.setItemsPerPage = function (num) {
                    $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
                    $scope.currentPage = 1; //reset to first page
                }
      
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="employeeController">
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:40px;">
        <div style="text-align: center">
                                    <ul uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" direction-links="true" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages"></ul>
                                </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>City</th>
                                <th>Country</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody >
                            <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage))" ng-style="set_color(emp)">
                                <td>{{emp.Name}} </td>
                                <td>{{emp.City}}</td>
                                <td>{{emp.Country}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: center">
                                    <ul uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" direction-links="true" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages"></ul>
                                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The template:

```
<pagination total-items="totalCount"
            ng-model="currentPage"
            items-per-page="limit"
            max-size="maxSize"
            rotate="false"
            class="pagination-sm pull-right"
            next-text="&rsaquo;"
            previous-text="&lsaquo;"
            first-text="&laquo;"
            last-text="&raquo;"
            boundary-links="true"
            ng-change="user_list()">
</pagination>
```

And the javascript:

```
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.limit = 100;
$scope.maxSize = 12;
```